# Query consecutive days records effectively

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Query consecutive days records effectively.

Let's say I have tables `hotels`, `rooms`, `room_skus`

Hotel HAS_MANY Room

Room HAS_MANY RoomSku (RoomSku has a date field)

[image: inline]

I can take the `location` and `date_range` as the params from the user.

eg. L.A.  2016-08-12~2016-08-18

The above params mean I need to fileter all the hotels in L.A. first. And then find the rooms which have available room_skus from `2016-08-12~2016-08-18`

How could I write the query more effeciently.

The query in PostgreSQL looks like this

```
      Room Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" IN (492, 76, 1187)
      Hotel Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE "hotels"."id" IN (13, 42,  357, 368, 378)
      RoomSku Load (3.6ms)  SELECT "room_skus".* FROM "room_skus" WHERE "room_skus"."room_id" IN (73, 74, 75, 2267)  ORDER BY date
       (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM("room_sku_stocks"."amount") FROM "room_sku_stocks" WHERE "room_sku_stocks"."room_sku_id" = $1  [["room_sku_id", 1047]]
      HotelImage Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "hotel_images".* FROM "hotel_images" WHERE "hotel_images"."hotel_id" = $1  ORDER BY "hotel_images"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["hotel_id", 13]]
       (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM("room_sku_stocks"."amount") FROM "room_sku_stocks" WHERE "room_sku_stocks"."room_sku_id" = $1  [["room_sku_id", 1034]]
      CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "hotel_images".* FROM "hotel_images" WHERE "hotel_images"."hotel_id" = $1  ORDER BY "hotel_images"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["hotel_id", 13]]
       (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM("room_sku_stocks"."amount") FROM "room_sku_stocks" WHERE "room_sku_stocks"."room_sku_id" = $1  [["room_sku_id", 1021]]
      .....
      CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "hotel_images".* FROM "hotel_images" WHERE "hotel_images"."hotel_id" = $1  ORDER BY "hotel_images"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["hotel_id", 378]]
      Rendered api/v1/room_skus/search.json.jbuilder (468.4ms)
```

Here's my current query, its complexity looks so terrible.

```
      // suppose I get the hotel ids first, and try to filter available rooms from this function
      def get_available_rooms_in_a_row(start_date, end_date, hotel_ids, num_of_days_in_a_row)
        all_room_ids = RoomSku.get_room_ids(start_date, end_date, hotel_ids)
        available_rooms_ids = get_filtered_available_rooms_ids(all_room_ids, num_of_days_in_a_row)
        Room.includes(:hotel, :skus).where(id: available_rooms_ids)
      end
```

# fetch all room_sku_ids and check if the # of available room_sku_ids is above the num_of_days_in_a_row, 
  # if so, then this room is qualified. (the filter is on Ruby level not SQL level)

```
          def get_filtered_available_rooms_ids(room_ids, num_of_days_in_a_row)
            room_frequence = {}
            room_ids.each do |i|
              if room_frequence.has_key? i
                room_frequence[i]+=1
              else
                room_frequence[i] = 1
              end
            end
            room_frequence.reject { |k, v| v < num_of_days_in_a_row }.keys
          end
```

And in the response JSON is also a headache question,

I will get Rooms from the above functions,

But the returned  JSON is a aggregation of valia room_sku_ids and its Hotel and Room infomation.

Let's say. The return Rooms are #1 and #2

However, the Room #1 has room_sku_ids from `2016-01-01 ~ 2018-12-31`

But what I need is the info of room_sku_ids from `2016-08-12~2016-08-18`

Therefore you can see I wrote a `isOutOfDataRange` to filter those room_sku_ids which are out of date range.

```
        def isOutOfDataRange(room_sku_date)
          (room_sku_date< @checkin_date or room_sku_date > @checkout_date )
        end

        json.array!(@rooms) do |item|
          json.hotel item.hotel
          json.room_skus do
            json.array! item.skus do |sku|
              next if isOutOfDataRange(sku.date)
              json.merge! sku.attributes.merge({stock:sku.stock})
            end
          end
        end
```

Overall, I think these query is terrible and not-effective.

Any idea or direction to prove my code?

## Sample output: Object of Array, each object is a aggregation of RoomSkuid and its Room, Hotel information

[image: inline]

### SAMPLE JSON

```
  [  
     {  
        "id":73,
        "hotel_id":13,
        "name":"單人房",
        "guests":1,
        "created_at":"2016-08-10T17:03:40.302Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-08-10T17:03:40.302Z",
        "english_name":"Single Room",
        "hotel":{  
           "id":13,
           "name":"東京郎伍德飯店",
           "introduction":null,
           "city_id":1,
           "created_at":"2016-08-10T17:03:40.300Z",
           "updated_at":"2016-08-10T17:03:40.311Z",
           "checkin_time":null,
           "checkout_time":null,
           "region":"上野",
           "english_name":"Hotel Lungwood Tokyo",
        },
        "room_skus":[  
           {  
              "id":1047,
              "room_id":73,
              "price":4000,
              "date":"2016-08-17",
              "created_at":"2016-08-10T17:04:05.161Z",
              "updated_at":"2016-08-10T17:04:05.170Z",
              "saleable":true,
              "annotation":null,
              "state":"active",
              "cost":3000.0,
              "stock":6
           }
        ],
        "img_src_url":"/img/hotel.jpg"
     },
     .....
     {  
        "id":2267,
        "hotel_id":378,
        "name":"三人房",
        "guests":3,
        "created_at":"2016-08-10T17:03:45.364Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-08-10T17:03:45.364Z",
        "english_name":"Triple Room",
        "hotel":{  
           "id":378,
           "name":"名古屋駅前名鐵飯店",
           "introduction":null,
           "city_id":3,
           "created_at":"2016-08-10T17:03:45.357Z",
           "updated_at":"2016-08-10T17:03:45.367Z",
           "checkin_time":null,
           "checkout_time":null,
           "region":"名古屋",
           "english_name":"Meitetsu Inn Nagoya Ekimae",
        },
        "room_skus":[  
           {  
              "id":30690,
              "room_id":2267,
              "price":3000,
              "date":"2016-08-17",
              "saleable":true,
              "annotation":null,
              "state":"active",
              "cost":2500.0,
              "stock":26
           }
        ],
        "img_src_url":"/img/hotel.jpg"
     }
  ]
```

## Response of Matt solution

I got  `ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown - unknown`

LINE 16: ... t.RoomDateCount = DATE_PART('date', '2016-08-18' - '2016-08...
                                                              ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       *
       ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY r.Id) as RoomDateCount
    FROM
       hotels h
       INNER JOIN rooms r
       ON h.Id = r.hotel_id
       INNER JOIN room_skus s
       ON r.id = s.room_id
       AND s.date BETWEEN '2016-08-12' AND '2016-08-18'
    ) t
WHERE
    t.RoomDateCount = DATE_PART('date', '2016-08-18' - '2016-08-12');
```

[image: inline]

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and expected output? This look very simple to do in plain SQL. So worst case if you cant convert the sql to ruby, just create a function on postgres.

Comment: I will provide you an sample output soon~ thx

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza pls take a look on the updated information, thank you :D

Comment: what is SKU? is like a room A is free day 1, 2 and 3 has three SKU?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza a Room has many room_sku. For example, If I want to stay in Room A on 2016-08-12 , I need to check if there is a room_sku which date is 2016-08-12 and its room_id is equal to `Room A`. is it clear ? thank you

Comment: so if you want rent a room three day, you need have three skus for the same room? otherwise you will be switching rooms?

Comment: Yes, if I want to stay in `2016-08-12 ~ 2016-08-15`  and there must be 3 skus, 2016-08-12, 2016-08-13, 2016-08-14 which are belong to the same Room. If so, I will pick it in the response.

Comment: where you get if sku is available or not? and do you have access to the db by pgAdmin or something?

Comment: @matt I see `id` and `room_id` on the json

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm not good at SQL, the queries implemented by Ruby ActiveRecord.

Comment: lol and I dont know Ruby. But this look very easy on SQL, if I show you the query you may translate to Ruby?

Comment: By the hierarchy, room has hotel_id as its foreign key , room_sku has room_id as foreign key. Each item of output JSON mean a room_sku and combines room and hotel information together, its quite complex T__T sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120821/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-newbike).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Actually, I can embeded RAW SQL in Ruby on Rails, pure POSTGRESQL query is fine. But could the returned information also include room and hotel information, so I can avoid N+1 queries ans speed up the respond time ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       *
       ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY r.Id) as RoomDateCount
    FROM
       Hotel h
       INNER JOIN Room r
       ON h.Id = r.hotel_id
       INNER JOIN RommSku s
       ON r.id = s.room_id
       AND s.date BETWEEN '2016-08-12' AND '2016-08-18'
       AND s.saleable = 1
    ) t
WHERE
    t.RoomDateCount = DATE_PART('day', '2016-08-18' - '2016-08-12')
```

I think this will give you want you want, you might have to play with date filter or count adding 1 day depending on your exact desired results.  All columns in hotels, room, and RoomSku would be available and I suggest specifically hard coding the ones you want for performance.

This does assume only 1 RoomSku per room per Date exists in your RoomSku table if multiple can exist then it would need slight tweak.

Comment: well Matt beat me while I was asking for more details.  To add some explanation. You try to find `room_sku` between a date range. If you find `N = Count(room_sku)` and `N = number days in date_range`  you have the the right room.

Comment: @matt I tied your solution, but got a exception. but that's my fault, you don't see the table schema

Comment: ? I didn't follow that did you figure out the exception?  Feel free to update your question with your current attempt if you still are getting an exception and detail what the exception is and we can look at it for you

Comment: @Matt Hi I updated it in the end of my post, the exception is that `ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown - unknown
LINE 16: ... t.RoomDateCount = DATE_PART('date', '2016-08-18' - '2016-08...
                                                              ^`

Comment: DATE_PART('date', '2016-08-18' - '2016-08-12') should be DATE_PART('day', '2016-08-18' - '2016-08-12')  you have 'date' where 'day' should be